# Runtime object reference

Tags: corba

If CORBA doesn't know about an object at compile time, how does CORBA identify an object passed to it at runtime?
How does it access that object at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

CORBA uses Object References. For inter ORB (the middleware framework code running on your machine) communication, Interoperable Object References - [IORs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interoperable_Object_Reference) are used. These are string based and contain host, port, policies and other stuff.

You need an objects reference to act with it the CORBA way (location transparent, remote). This reference than is "narrowed" , i.e., the middleware connects to the remote site. After that, every call to the object is a remote call, but you won't notice than in the application as you can handle the object as it where local.